# FadeIn and FadeOut effect to toggle boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nqbdap

Guys, i made this simple code and there is something wrong with him, and i can't.. i just can't figure out why.

In the first toggle change, the box one will disappear without the fadeOut effect, them will work normally.

Code:

```js
  var clickHandler = function(e) {
    var target = $(this).data('open');
    var box = $('.box');
    var active = 'box__active';
 
    if (!(box.eq(target).hasClass(active))) {
      box
      .fadeOut(500, function() {
    box.removeClass(active)
      });

      box.eq(target)
      .delay(500).fadeIn(500, function() {
        box.eq(target).addClass(active);
      });
    }
    
    
    
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  $(document).on('click', '[data-open]', clickHandler);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
.box__active {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>

<a data-open="0">Open one</a><br/>
<a data-open="1">Open two</a><br/>
<a data-open="2">Open three</a><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="box box__one box__active">One</div>
<div class="box">Two</div>
<div class="box">Three</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should know  that .eq() in jquery start index with 0  not with 1 .. so if I understand well you should use

```
 var target = $(this).data('open') - 1;
```

and for better code use .parseInt

```
var target = parseInt($(this).data('open')) - 1;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvoRMO)

you just need to use `$(this)`

```
$(this).removeClass(active);
$(this).addClass(active);
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNVgEK)

Comment: do you know why the fade effect doesn't occurs in the first change?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit. Now it is working at first time.

```js
  var clickHandler = function(e) {
    var target = $(this).data('open');
    var box = $('.box');
 
    box.fadeOut(500);
    box.eq(target).delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  $(document).on('click', '[data-open]', clickHandler);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>

<a data-open="0">Open one</a><br/>
<a data-open="1">Open two</a><br/>
<a data-open="2">Open three</a><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="box" style="display:inline-block;">One</div>
<div class="box">Two</div>
<div class="box">Three</div>
```